# Running test of hyperledger fabric-sdk-node

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker-compose, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

I'm trying to run test of the hyperledger fabric client node but I have some issues. Indeed, when I run the command `gulp test` I have lots of errors which look like this:

```
    not ok 586 Error: SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE at ClientDuplexStream.<anonymous> (C:\Users\A671975\go\src\github.com\hyperledger\fabric-sdk-node\node_
    modules\fabric-client\lib\Orderer.js:9:4530) at emitOne (events.js:96:13) at ClientDuplexStream.emit (events.js:188:7) at ClientDuplexStream.
    _emitStatusIfDone (C:\Users\A671975\go\src\github.com\hyperledger\fabric-sdk-node\node_modules\grpc\src\node\src\client.js:204:12) at ClientD
    uplexStream._readsDone (C:\Users\A671975\go\src\github.com\hyperledger\fabric-sdk-node\node_modules\grpc\src\node\src\client.js:169:8) at rea
    dCallback (C:\Users\A671975\go\src\github.com\hyperledger\fabric-sdk-node\node_modules\grpc\src\node\src\client.js:229:12)
      ---
        operator: fail
        at: Client.newDefaultKeyValueStore.then.then.then.then.then.then (C:\Users\A671975\go\src\github.com\hyperledger\fabric-sdk-node\test\int
    egration\e2e\create-channel.js:211:5)
        stack: |-
          Error: Error: SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE
              at ClientDuplexStream.<anonymous> (C:\Users\A671975\go\src\github.com\hyperledger\fabric-sdk-node\node_modules\fabric-client\lib\Or
    derer.js:9:4530)
              at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
              at ClientDuplexStream.emit (events.js:188:7)
              at ClientDuplexStream._emitStatusIfDone (C:\Users\A671975\go\src\github.com\hyperledger\fabric-sdk-node\node_modules\grpc\src\node\
    src\client.js:204:12)
              at ClientDuplexStream._readsDone (C:\Users\A671975\go\src\github.com\hyperledger\fabric-sdk-node\node_modules\grpc\src\node\src\cli
    ent.js:169:8)
              at readCallback (C:\Users\A671975\go\src\github.com\hyperledger\fabric-sdk-node\node_modules\grpc\src\node\src\client.js:229:12)
              at Test.assert [as _assert] (C:\Users\A671975\go\src\github.com\hyperledger\fabric-sdk-node\node_modules\tape\lib\test.js:212:54)
              at Test.bound [as _assert] (C:\Users\A671975\go\src\github.com\hyperledger\fabric-sdk-node\node_modules\tape\lib\test.js:64:32)
              at Test.fail (C:\Users\A671975\go\src\github.com\hyperledger\fabric-sdk-node\node_modules\tape\lib\test.js:277:10)
              at Test.bound [as fail] (C:\Users\A671975\go\src\github.com\hyperledger\fabric-sdk-node\node_modules\tape\lib\test.js:64:32)
              at Client.newDefaultKeyValueStore.then.then.then.then.then.then (C:\Users\A671975\go\src\github.com\hyperledger\fabric-sdk-node\tes
    t\integration\e2e\create-channel.js:211:5)
              at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:129:7)
```

I think this is due to an error of connexion between the tests and the containers but I don't understand what I have to do in order to solve it. So if someone had this error before, please share the solution ;) Thanks !

Comment: would need more information about your environment. Can you please add a gist of the output from 'docker images' and 'docker ps -a'. Thanks.

Comment: did you ever find resolution for this issue?  I'm hitting up against it... guessing it's just a config file or something the docs I'm following neglect to address...